# I cannot root my Android subsystem on Chrome OS

Tags: rooting, chromebook

I want to root my Android subsystem (I believe that is what it's called) and I have gone on many sites that tell how to do this. I still cannot do what I want to do. I have an HP Chromebook 14a with Octopus Android 11. I want to root the Android on my Chromebook so I can use apps like GameGuardian.

I have gone onto sites like Github with their more modern tool, CrAnberry. Others are more outdated, and thus, they are practically useless. There were no results from either Github or the rest of the World Wide Web.

Comment: Please describe what you want to do, what you already tried and what where the results.

Comment: Xda Dev is probably where you'll find the best Android rooting information.

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out for days.
Nolirium seems to have stop working 2 years ago.
There was a newer attempt by CerisWhite, the CrAnberry, but it doesn't work on newer updates running Android 10 in the containers.